# integrating to find a mean

Tags: integration, means

I am trying to find the mean of the function $\exp(-2r)$ in 2 dimensions. This should then be the equivalent of doing

$$\frac{\int\!\int\!\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}{\int\!\int\!e^{-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}$$

Unfortunately, do not know how to do either integral. I tried u substitution with the top one, but I keep ending up with an extra $2x$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know polar coordinates? The integrals are much easier to compute in polar coordinates.

Comment: Fortunately you can utilise the polar integral. But more than that you can use differentiating under the integral sign.

Comment: I believe that the definition of average is not correct.  I really want to help so please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: That formula for the mean doesn't look right. It should be the integral of the exponential over $U$ divided by the area of $U.$ Here $U$ is a bounded region in the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one dimension, the average $<f>$ of a function $F$ on the interval $(a,b)$ is

$$<f>=\frac{\int_a^{b} f(x)dx}{\int_a^{b} 1dx}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^{b} f(x)dx$$

For $n$-dimensions, the average $<f>$ of a function $f$ defined on a finite domain $\mathscr{D}$ is given

$$\frac{\int_\mathscr{D} f d^nx}{\int_\mathscr{D} 1 d^nx}$$

In the $2$-D case presented, $f=e^{-2r}$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the domain is $\mathscr{R}^2$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
<e^{-2r}>&=\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R e^{-2r} rdrd\phi}{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R 1 rdrd\phi}\\\\
&=\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{2\pi\left(\frac14-\frac14(2R+1)e^{-2R}\right)}{\pi R^2}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

NOTE:

If one is finding the average of $r$ under the measure $e^{-2r}$, then

$$<r>=\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R e^{-2r} rdrd\phi}{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R e^{-2r} drd\phi}=\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{2\pi\left(\frac14-\frac14(2R+1)e^{-2R}\right)}{\pi (1-e^{-2R})}=\frac12$$

Comment: Maybe I am trying to answer the wrong question. My question is, at what radius is there as much stuff inside that radius ring as there is outside?